# SSL Connect Error using HTTP Caller in FME

Tags: fme-form, ssl

I am using a HTTP Caller in FME Desktop to connect to a SAP OData service. This is a https service. It works in Google Chrome and it works in FME when I use Fiddler, but it doesn't work without Fiddler. I receive a SSL Connect Error. What should I do next?

Comment: Using FME 2017 I am assuming?

Comment: FYI Guide > https://youtu.be/AcUz6Q0nipI?t=15m29s and the live (recorded) demo of this is at https://youtu.be/AcUz6Q0nipI?t=21m12s

Comment: I use FME 2015.1, which is totally different Should I upgrade or is it also possible in FME 2015.1?

Comment: There has been major improvements with HTTPS and OAuth in this years version of FME (2017).

Answer (score 1):

I had a look through our developer database and it sounds like a problem that existed sending the User-Agent header with a HTTP CONNECT request.

Your Fiddler logs may show that. Also, the GET command works, but you obviously can't do a GET unless there's a CONNECT first, so that won't help.

In short, the problem was fixed in FME2016 build 16078 - so if you can upgrade to that build or later then you should find the issue resolved.

If you upgrade and are still finding a problem, then contact the [Safe support team](http://safe.com/support) and mention PR#63763.